# Объединение запросов MySQL + group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

Есть таблица звонков:

```
CREATE TABLE `asterisk`.`calls` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dt_start` DATETIME NULL,
  `disposition` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Выполняю следующий запрос с группировкой:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE(dt_start), '%d %M') AS `dt`,
    COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
FROM
    calls
WHERE
    DATE(dt_start) >= '2018-05-25'
        AND DATE(dt_start) <= '2018-06-31'
        AND disposition = 'YES'
GROUP BY DATE(dt_start)
```

Получаю результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

 Необходимо 3м столбцом вывести результат с условием:

```
disposition != 'YES'
```

(условие по датам оставить то же)

Это возможно сделать в рамках этого же запроса?

Comment: Конечно, в чем проблема? попробуйте - `disposition` not like 'YES'

Comment: Проблем в том, чтобы это было 3м столбцом. COUNT(*) AS `cnt` - тут ='YES', COUNT(*) AS `cnt_2` - тут !+ 'YES'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будем использовать не COUNT(*), а SUM с условием.
Так как я не знаю, что кроме "yes" есть в этой таблице, поэтому назвал альтернативу "not_yes".

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE(dt_start), '%d %M') AS `dt`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `disposition` = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) AS `yes`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `disposition` <> 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) AS `not_yes`
FROM
  `calls`
WHERE
  DATE(dt_start) >= '2018-05-25'
  AND DATE(dt_start) <= '2018-06-31'
GROUP BY `dt`;
```

Пример полученных данных

```
+------------+------+---------+
| dt         | yes  | not_yes |
+------------+------+---------+
| 01 January |    1 |       2 |
| 21 June    |    6 |       3 |
+------------+------+---------+
```

Также я поправил GROUP BY. Ваш запрос будет работать в старых версиях мускула, в новом будет ошибка группировки:

```
ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.calls.dt_start' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! То что нужно. Мне нужно вытащить по условию =YES и !=YES, там может быть множество других рандомных значений.